# Matching face from different images

Tags: c++, opencv

I am beginner in OpenCV. I've detected face successfully and now what i am trying to do is matching the faces from two different images and returning the true or false value. How can i do this in openCV using c++ please help

Answer (score 2):

Face recognition is an advanced method.

There is a website devoted for this : http://www.face-rec.org/

It contains lot of research papers, algorithms etc to do face recognition. You can find similar sites by googling.

Two popular method used for this purposes are:

**1. Eigen Faces:**

To understand this, below wikipedia passage is good:

`A set of eigenfaces can be generated by performing a mathematical process called principal component analysis (PCA) on a large set of images depicting different human faces. Informally, eigenfaces can be considered a set of "standardized face ingredients", derived from statistical analysis of many pictures of faces. Any human face can be considered to be a combination of these standard faces. For example, one's face might be composed of the average face plus 10% from eigenface 1, 55% from eigenface 2, and even -3% from eigenface 3. Remarkably, it does not take many eigenfaces combined together to achieve a fair approximation of most faces. Also, because a person's face is not recorded by a digital photograph, but instead as just a list of values (one value for each eigenface in the database used), much less space is taken for each person's face.`

First 32 eigen faces of a face (obtained from http://www.shervinemami.info/faceRecognition.html)

[image]

A C++ implementation of this method can be found at http://www.shervinemami.info/faceRecognition.html.

**2. Fisher Faces:**

This uses another method called Linear Discriminant Analysis. 
For more details visit: http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Fisherfaces

eg: First 4 fisher faces of an image

[image]

***Finally, you can find all details code about them from  [this pdf.](http://www.bytefish.de/pdf/facerec_python.pdf) And you can find its C++ implementation in [this github repo](https://github.com/bytefish/facerecognition_guide).***

For your information, the above implementation has been added to OpenCV mainstream from version 2.4-beta onwards ([View changelog here](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/ChangeLog)). Even the codes are included in [cpp samples](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/raw/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/facerec_demo.cpp) that come with OpenCV 2.4-beta.

Comment: +1 Horrible question, but this answer is interesting and educational (even for me). Do you work with OpenCV on a daily basis?

Comment: Yeah.. I don't have any other things to spend time.